# Apache configuration to allow direct navigation to React's client-side Urls

Tags: reactjs, apache, amazon-s3, react-router, reverse-proxy

We are developing a Reactjs app that we deploy as a static application in S3 and then have an Apache Server reverse proxy SSL terminator in front of it to provide security and authentication. We currently have Apache `location` directives that use `regex` matchers to route requests from the Apache public hostnames to the backend Reactjs static app on S3. Everything works if we load the index.html or homepage and interact with the links. However, attempting to navigate directly to a React client-side URL configured in the app leads to `403 - forbidden` errors.

E.g., the Reactjs' home (which routes to the index.html on S3) is like
`https://base.host.com` while the S3 URL (${S3_REACT_URL} in the code snippet below) is of the form `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/app-bucket-name`.

Attempting to navigate directlu to `https://base.host.com/views/overview` directly without clicking its link on the home or index page fails with this S3 error as there is no corresponding file for the path.

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>98BD9C4EB0D869DA</RequestId><HostId>Fcaj++J6l4qV10mlEq4cIZOw6slT0kxjnOgad5wsYTEFoBDxDQiOhfHwxkEiaM8Qml7SrWltZOI=</HostId></Error>
```

I have tried different configurations using mod rewrite to see if I can get this routing to work but without success. I am not also sure how mod rewrite will work with our current settings that have only `location` directives for all mappings.

**React route configuration**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <DashboardProvider>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
          <Route exact path="/views/:id" component={GraphView} />
          <Route exact path="/cpp-dashboard" component={CPPDashboardPage} />
          <Route path="*" render={() => <span>Route not found</span>} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </DashboardProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Apache configuration**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu -o pipefail

API_URL=$(cat $1 | jq -r '.configuration.API_URL')
echo $API_URL

S3_REACT_URL=$(cat $1 | jq -r '.configuration.S3_REACT_URL')
echo $S3_REACT_URL

cat > /etc/httpd/conf.d/abc-httpd-includes/https_vhost/proxypass.inc <<EOF
ProxyRequests Off
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/private/client_crt_rsa.pem

<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>

<LocationMatch "^$" >
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ProxyPassMatch "${S3_REACT_URL}/index.html" retry=\${CLOUD_HTTPS_PROXY_RETRY} keepalive=\${CLOUD_HTTPS_PROXY_KEEPALIVE} nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse "${S3_REACT_URL}/index.html"
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^\/(.+)$" >
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ProxyPassMatch "${S3_REACT_URL}/\$1" retry=\${CLOUD_HTTPS_PROXY_RETRY} keepalive=\${CLOUD_HTTPS_PROXY_KEEPALIVE} nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse "${S3_REACT_URL}/\$1"
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^\/(v\d+)\/(.+)$" >
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ProxyPassMatch "${API_URL}/\$1/\$2" retry=\${CLOUD_HTTPS_PROXY_RETRY} keepalive=\${CLOUD_HTTPS_PROXY_KEEPALIVE} nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse "${API_URL}/\$1/\$2"
</LocationMatch>

EOF
```

I would like to be able to navigate directly to the Reactjs client-side routes without having to go through the index.html or homepage. Thank you very much for your assistance.